# why do watchdog cause high load average

Tags: 12.04, cpu-load

I have encountered a problem of high load average. I find out that it's the watchdog process that keeps in running status. I could not figure it out.

```
top - 12:08:40 up 182 days, 44 min,  2 users,  load average: 22.21, 22.19, 22.21
Tasks: 204 total,  24 running, 180 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.4%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16267928k total, 14761896k used,  1506032k free,   302652k buffers
Swap:  3906556k total,    36120k used,  3870436k free, 13414008k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                        
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:45 watchdog/0                                                                                     
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/1                                                                                     
   16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/2                                                                                     
   20 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/3                                                                                     
   24 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/4                                                                                     
   28 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/5                                                                                     
   32 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/6                                                                                     
   36 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/7                                                                                     
   40 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/8                                                                                     
   44 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/9                                                                                     
   48 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/10                                                                                    
   52 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/11                                                                                    
   56 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/12                                                                                    
   60 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/13                                                                                    
   64 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/14                                                                                    
   68 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/15                                                                                    
   76 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300259:14 watchdog/17                                                                                    
   80 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:45 watchdog/18                                                                                    
   82 root      20   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0  5119411h kworker/19:0                                                                                   
   84 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300259:16 watchdog/19                                                                                    
   88 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:45 watchdog/20                                                                                    
   92 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:44 watchdog/21                                                                                    
  100 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0 300258:45 watchdog/23                                                                                    
22791 root      20   0 17456 1376  944 R    0  0.0   0:00.04 top                                                                                            
    1 root      20   0 24200 1608 1176 S    0  0.0  5654552h init                                                                                           
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                       
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  5129099h ksoftirqd/0                                                                                    
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0 562040:00 migration/0
```

My system version is：

```
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Anyone help? Thanks a lot！

Comment: I would suggest that you update your system, as the kernel you are using is very old. The current kernel is `3.2.0-87-generic #125-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 08:25:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. You might be suffering from fragmented memory, but I have nothing to backup that statement and your particular `top` snapshot CPU use doesn't agree with your load average.

Comment: Thanks to Doug Smythies! It's true that my CPU use is very low and load average is high. It seems just having too many running watchdog process. This machine is in service, could not update the kernel right now. If it's the fragmented memory, should the CPU use be higher? Is there any tool could help to check the fragmented memory?

Comment: Too many watchdog processes: I assumed you have 24 CPUs in your system, one watchdog process per CPU. Fragmented memory: Yes, I think it would show in top as high system time, but am not sure. You could try flushing the buffers: `echo "3" | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: I have tried the command, but it doesn't work, getting a lot of free memory. I am going to reboot the system.